# Como permitir conteúdo javascript em um iframe?

Tags: html5, iframe

Preciso mostrar um `iframe` dentro de uma página HTML, o problema é que o conteúdo `Javascript` em geral não funciona:

```
<iframe src="minhapasta/minhapagina.php?url=exemplo.com" width="1600" height="1000" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation "  seamless="seamless" >  </iframe>
```

Já tentei todo o tipo de `sandbox` no `iframe` mas não vai!

Tem alguma alternativa ao `iframe` que eu possa utilizar?

Comment: O que é que não funciona? podes mostrar o código que queres usar?

Comment: na verdade estou tentando exibir o site do sportingbet:
`https://br.sportingbet.com` mas a área de ao vivo que é javascript e os times na área de futebol não carrega, e percebo que é porque na verdade, nenhum script está sendo carregado.

Comment: Pode ser que o site não permita "referrer" (horrivelmente grafado "referer" no header) diferente do original, já testou para ter certeza?

Comment: Testei, não é isso! :(